# How to pass multiple path variables for spring boot controller class in GET method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

i am trying to pass multiple path variables to my controller class in GET method, so i am giving variables through POSTMAN, When i tried for single variable it's working fine, but for two variables i am getting empty result.

This is how i am passing variables through POSTMAN
localhost:8081/specquestions/java/oops

here 'java' is one variable and 'oops' is one more variable

My java controller class

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/specquestions/{subject}/{topic}")
public ResponseEntity<List<QuestionBank>> getSpecificQuestions(@PathVariable String subject,String topic) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok( questionBankService.getSpecificquestions(subject,topic));

}
```

Can any one please suggest me where i did mistake.

Comment: Your forgot to annotate the second argument with `@PathVariable`, just like the first one.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much, yeah now it's working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add @PathVariable for second parameter in controller like below

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/specquestions/{subject}/{topic}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<QuestionBank>> getSpecificQuestions(@PathVariable String subject,@PathVariable String topic) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok( questionBankService.getSpecificquestions(subject,topic));

    }
```